# GeoPandas unable to read in PostGIS table

Tags: python, pandas, postgis, geopandas

I am attempting to read columns from a PostGIS table into a GeoDataFrame and am getting the following issue:

```
df = geo.GeoDataFrame.from_postgis("select geom __geometry__, id 
from hist_line limit 5",con, geom_col='__geometry__')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/stephen/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3066, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-137-0f8eeafc0543>", line 1, in <module>
    df9 = geo.GeoDataFrame.from_postgis("select geom as __geometry__, id     from hist_line limit 5",con, geom_col='__geometry__')
  File "/Users/stephen/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py", line 201, in from_postgis
coerce_float, params)
  File "/Users/stephen/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/geopandas/io/sql.py", line 42, in read_postgis
    s = wkb_geoms.apply(lambda x: shapely.wkb.loads(binascii.unhexlify(x.encode())))
  File "/Users/stephen/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2169, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas/src/inference.pyx", line 1059, in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas/lib.c:62578)
  File "/Users/stephen/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/geopandas/io/sql.py", line 42, in <lambda>
    s = wkb_geoms.apply(lambda x: shapely.wkb.loads(binascii.unhexlify(x.encode())))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

The table has the structure:

```
CREATE TABLE hist_point (
id BIGINT NOT NULL,
version SMALLINT NOT NULL,
visible BOOLEAN,
user_id INTEGER,
user_name TEXT,
valid_from TIMESTAMP,
valid_to TIMESTAMP,
tags HSTORE,
geom GEOMETRY(POINT,900913),
typ1 CHAR,
typ TEXT,
minor INTEGER,
CONSTRAINT hist_point_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id, version   )
```

The table is populated with data from OpenStreetMaps.  I have been able to load data from this table into normal Pandas DataFrames - so no issue with the database connection, so am unsure why it's not working for GeoPandas.

I am using Python 2.7 loaded via Anaconda (and GeoPandas loaded using 'pip install geopandas') on OSX 10.11.

And insight would be much appreciated.

Thank you,
Stephen.

Comment: Do you have NULL values in the geometry column?

Comment: Thank you!  Yes I do, and skipping them has resolved the issue.